# Capping a bathroom faucet?

Tags: leak, faucet, temporary

I have a bathroom faucet that leaks hot water. There's no valve between the hot water tank and the sink.

I figure I have a few options in the short term:

1. Drain the tank before replacing the washer
2. Attempt to replace the washer without turning off the water
3. Cap the faucet, which feels threaded.

The last option seems like the easiest short term solution until I can hire a plumber. But I'm not sure if there are repercussions such as the risk of having hot water flow back through the cold water line.

Any thoughts / suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Unless the water heater tank is above this sink, all you need to do is turn off the water, (and turn off the water heater as well for good measure)  not *drain* the water heater.

Comment: @ecnerwal There is in fact a cold water intake valve for the tank, so this seems like the simplest solution. I'll turn the tank down to pilot and wait a bit, then turn off the cold water intake, then see if the sink upstairs stops spitting out hot water. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely install valves while the water's off so you don't have to do this dance again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is the order of steps I would take;

1. Shut off main water valve.
2. Open hot water tap, drain the line.
3. Replace washer.
4. Optional, cut hot water line, add a shutoff value under sink. Probably a good idea to do the cold water line as well if not already present. If you're not experienced with soldering/plumbing then you could use a "Sharkbite" click and connect water valve.